# Agrupar valores de array y sumar sus valores en PHP

Tags: php, array

Buenas tengo varios días tratando de hacer lo que les voy a explicar. He probado varias funciones pero no logro dar con la correcta y no se que hacer.
Tengo el siguiente Arreglo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06046425
    [1] => 20
)
Array
(
    [0] => 06046425
    [1] => 20
)
Array
(
    [0] => 21343093
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 22392589
    [1] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 22392589
    [1] => 15
)
```

Donde [0] es el identificador único de la persona y [1] es un valor que quiero sumar siempre y cuando [0] sea igual; osea la salida debería quedar así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06046425
    [1] => 40
)
Array
(
    [0] => 21343093
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 22392589
    [1] => 20
)
```

¿Como puedo puedo agrupar los [0] que estén repetidos en el arreglo y sumar los [1] y los que no estén repetidos los deje con el mismo valor?

Comment: No se me viene una funcion a la mente pero podrias ordenarlo e ir recorriendo el array con un for...
Ciando cambie el elemento [0] volves a 0 la variable.
Rso lo vas pasando a un segundo array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo la respuesta aqui para que alguien le sirva

```
function qd_sd($array, $campo, $campo2) {
   $nuevo = array();
   foreach ($array as $parte) {
   $clave[] = $parte[$campo];
   }
   $unico = array_unique($clave);
      foreach ($unico as $un) {
         foreach ($array as $original) {
            if ($un == $original[$campo]) {
               $fecha2 = '04:30';//aqui pueden omitir esto 
               $suma = $suma + minutosTranscurridos($original[$campo2],$fecha2);//  igual que la funcion minutosTranscurridos y el campo $fecha2
               }
            }
         $ele['cedula'] = $un;
         $ele['fecha'] = $suma;
         array_push($nuevo, $ele);
         $suma = 0;
      }
      return $nuevo;
}
```

Para llamar a la funcion hace esto

```
$chido = qd_sd($COLOCAR_SU_ARREGLO, 'cedula', 'fecha');
```